# Meaning of "scope" in D (for a parameter)

Tags: d

What does `scope` in

```
void foo(scope void* p) { }
```

mean?

(I'm not talking about `scope(exit)` or `scope int x = 5;`, but about `scope` as used inside a parameter list.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are 3 uses for `scope` in D.

1. `scope` statements. This is when you use `scope(success)`, `scope(failure)`, or `scope(exit)`. The statements in the block that follows are run when exiting the scope that the `scope` statement is in if no exception is thrown, if an exception is thrown, or regardless of whether an exception is thrown for success, failure, and exit respectively. This use of `scope` is staying in the language.
2. `scope` on a local variable. This puts the variable on the stack - even if it's a class. The object is destroyed when it leaves scope. This use of `scope` is unsafe and will eventually be removed from the language (though [std.typecons.scoped](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.scoped) replaces it for those who want to live life dangerously).
3. `scope` on a function parameter (which is the use case that you're asking about). When placed on a parameter that is a delegate, it means that references to that parameter cannot be escaped (i.e. assigned to a global variable). And when the compiler sees this on delegates, it will avoid allocating a closure when taking the address of a local function. This is essential in `opApply` loops ([reference post on newsgroup](http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D&artnum=122125)). Currently, `scope` has no effect on any function parameters other than delegates and is ignored for all other types, though it may or may not at some point in the future be expanded to affect types like pointers to prevent them from escaping the function.

When used on a function parameter, the `in` keyword is an alias for `const scope`, which is frequently how `scope` on function parameters gets inadvertently used.

Comment: I was looking for #3... that's amazing! I always wondered how to do that, thank you! :)

Comment: @Lambert: It seems this wasn't documented on the D website, but I've issued a report, so this will likely get added to the documentation soon.

Comment: @Jonathan please add mention that item number 2  (This puts the variable on the stack) **is deprecated**

https://dlang.org/deprecate.html

Comment: @user1432751 It's not deprecated. It's just planned to be deprecated and has been for ages - hence why that page lists "future" for its deprecation. And this answer has always stated that the this use of `scoped` will be removed. It just goes to show how slow we are at deprecating it though that it's still not deprecated over 5 years after this answer was posted. :( It did update the answer though to make it clearer that `scope` on function parameters currently only affects delegates.

Comment: To keep things up to date: If I'm reading that Deprecated page correctly, *scope* as a type-constraint is now deprecated, but *scope* as a storage-class is not deprecated, and there are no plans to make it deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Searching on the digital mars newsgroup, I found two semi-related post about scope in that context: [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/Documentation_of_scope_function_parameters_68720.html) and [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/scope_function_parameters_115143.html).

From reading those two post, function parameter scope doesn't seem to do anything useful and it's there for backwards compatibility. It even sounds like later versions after D2 might have that qualifier removed altogether.