# How to make destructors be called on going out of scope?

Tags: d

With GC on, is it possible for destructors to be called right after going out of scope.

Is it possible for destructors to be called on going out of scope for **all** objects [of any type]?

Why aren't destructors called when going out of scope anyway?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711309/meaning-of-scope-in-d-for-a-parameter) post "`scope` on a local variable" is said to be "unsafe". Why is it considered unsafe?
And the rationale for deprecating the feature is

> scope as a type constraint was a quirk in the language without a compelling use case.

No compelling use case? Like placing objects on the stack(this feature does that, right?) isn't faster than on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the D GC does not call destructors when returning from a function. The GC is triggered when an allocation occurs, and when [`GC.collect`](https://dlang.org/library/core/memory/gc.collect.html) is called.

D has [`scoped`](https://dlang.org/library/std/typecons/scoped.html), which wraps a non-RAII type in a struct, which has RAII behavior. This way, the struct's destructor can take care of cleaning up the memory. Note that, while this generally works, there are some corner cases and things to be aware of that a GC will handle automatically. This allows destructors to be called on any object when leaving a scope.

Destructors are not called on all objects when they leave scope because there may be other references to the objects. Consider this code:

```
int* global;

void func() {
    int* p = new int;
    global = p;
}
```

If the `int` pointed to by `p` was destructed when `func()` returned, then `global` would point to destructed memory.

The article you link is almost ten years old, and D has changed a bit in the meantime. `scope` now has better semantics, which meaningfully limit what you can do with variables marked such:

- [return ref](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#return-ref-parameters)
- [return scope](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#return-scope-parameters)
- [ref return scope](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#ref-return-scope-parameters)

`scope` local variables may still be assigned to globals, which seems like an oversight. I'll file a bug if I can't find an existing one.

Comment: I understand that there may be references to the objects. But why can't the destructor be called the moment the last reference is released?

Comment: That is possible, and is generally referred to as reference counting. There are some issues with reference counting that are handled by GC, just like there are some issues with GC that RC does better. Bacon et al covers this in [A Unified Theory of Garbage Collection](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~weimerw/2012-4610/reading/bacon-garbage.pdf).

D has chosen GC, but it's somewhat possible to use RC (see [refCounted](https://dlang.org/library/std/typecons/ref_counted.html) in D.

Comment: What about things like files? Since destructors are called by GC, it means handles to files are closed by GC too? Isn't that crazy?

Answer (score 1):

> With GC on, is it possible for destructors to be called right after going out of scope.
>
> Is it possible for destructors to be called on going out of scope for all objects [of any type]?

Destructors are called for any object on the stack, this applies to structs and classes allocated as `scope Foo f = new Foo()`.

> In this post "scope on a local variable" is said to be "unsafe". Why is it  considered unsafe?

Because one could escape a reference to the stack allocated instance which might outlive the current function call. (But DIP 25 / 1000 detect's most of these issues)

> And the rationale for deprecating the feature is [...]
> No compelling use case? Like placing objects on the stack(this feature does that, right?) isn't faster than on the heap.

Only `scope` attached to the type declaration is deprecated.

---

But as a general recommendation, use structs if your object requires deterministic destruction (e.g. `File` handles).